# What do you call this?

Tags: java

Is there a name for this techinique (method calls returning objects upon which another method call is made on the same line)?

```
String pAID = commonAssets.getApplicationServerSettings().getSetting("plivoAuthID");
```

instead of

```
ApplicationServerSettings applicationServerSettings = commonAssets.getApplicationServerSettings();
String pAID = applicationServerSettings.getSetting("plivoAuthID");
```

Also, when I do the first, Eclipse doesn't prompt me to import the class `ApplicationServerSettings`, but it does if I use the second code style.

Also, are these two styles merely preferences?

Comment: place different calls on different strings, e.g. place `.getSetting("plivoAuthID");` on another string (to be able to understand crash reports)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique is called [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

```
String pAID = commonAssets.getApplicationServerSettings().getSetting("plivoAuthID");
```

Definition from the wiki:

> Method chaining, also known as named parameter idiom, is a common
>   syntax for invoking multiple method calls in object-oriented
>   programming languages. Each method returns an object, allowing the
>   calls to be chained together in a single statement without requiring
>   variables to store the intermediate results.[1] Local variable
>   declarations are syntactic sugar because of the difficulty humans have
>   with deeply nested method calls.[2][3] A method chain is also known as
>   a train wreck due to the increase in the number of methods that come
>   one after another in the same line that occurs as more methods are
>   chained together[4] even though line breaks are often added between
>   methods.

Your second question:

Also, when I do the first, Eclipse doesn't prompt me to import the class ApplicationServerSettings, but it does if I use the second code style.

- From the definition again **"Each method returns an object, allowing the calls to be chained together in a single statement without requiring variables to store the intermediate results."** That is why it does not prompt you to import the class `ApplicationServerSettings`.

Another example (besides the want you introduce) that looks simpler:

Take a look at the wiki example:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // In addition to having the side-effect of setting the attributes in question,
    // the setters return "this" (the current Person object) to allow for further chained method calls.

    public Person setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Person setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public void introduce() {
        System.out.println("Hello, my name is " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.");
    }

    // Usage:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        // Output: Hello, my name is Peter and I am 21 years old.
        person.setName("Peter").setAge(21).introduce();
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't the method chaining exactly

Comment: I stand corrected! According to your quote, this does actually fit the description. It's just never how I've used the phrase before. I turned my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: "A method chain is also known as a train wreck" - beautiful!

Comment: ok, thanks @rainbolt. I think the definition matches 'method chaining', I was going to delete my answer but I believe this is what the user is asking for. 'String pAID = commonAssets.getApplicationServerSettings().getSetting("plivoAuthID");' this is method chaining for me.

Comment: Different definitions... Some people call it method chaining indeed

Comment: Method chaining doesn't *require* that all methods return the *same* object, though that is the most common use of the phrase "method chaining", however most use of the new stream API is rampant with method chaining, and rarely returns the same object.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  But I also asked why you can omit imports of these classes.  Does anyone know?

Comment: @justin because you don't have the intermediate step in which you store the ApplicationServerSettings variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's often called *fluent syntax*.

IMHO it's a matter of style, there's no right or wrong.

Fluent syntax is more concise, which is sometimes a good thing.

The other variant is more handy for source-level debugging. You can step through the statements and inspect the intermediate results.

Comment: "Fluent" pertains to a single special case of method chaining: when each subsequent call occurs on the _same_ object.